# Issue with sprites and collisions

Tags: swift, collision

In this app that I'm building, I want a small triangle to spin around and catch balls that fly towards it. Here's my question: how can I make it so that if the ball hits the OPEN end of the triangle, it adds to the score, and if the ball hits any CLOSED end of the triangle, it ends the game? Here's an image to give you an idea of what I mean:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/s58cH.png]

At first I thought I could just add another sprite *on top* of the triangle, but was never able to figure out how to rotate that in the correct way and still make it detect collisions like its supposed to.